# Webscraping question in python using Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to scrape using selenium in python.  I want the solar data from this site and section: https://www.caiso.com/TodaysOutlook/Pages/supply.html#section-renewables-trend [image]

I think the problem I'm having is that the `Chart data (CSV)` menu option does not function as a button so clicking it doesn't work.  This is what I see when I inspect the element before and after clicking it the "Chart data (CSV)" menu option.

Before: `<a class="dropdown-item mb-0" id="downloadRenewablesCSV" data-type="text/csv">Chart data (CSV)</a>`

After: `<a class="dropdown-item mb-0" id="downloadRenewablesCSV" data-type="text/csv" href="data:text/csv;charset=utf8,Renewables%2007%2F20%2 ...  [alot of encoded data] ...2C209%2C211%2C211%2C211%2C212%2C211%2C211%2C210%0A" download="CAISO-renewables-20220720.csv">Chart data (CSV)</a>`

originally I assumed it was just a button element that would download the csv file and was trying to do this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='PATH')
driver.get('https://www.caiso.com/TodaysOutlook/Pages/supply.html')
button = driver.find_element(by='xpath',value='/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[8]/div/div/div[2]/nav/div[3]/div/a[1]')
button.click()
```

This isn't working.  Any advice? I am very new to selenium sorry.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong, so I deleted the comment.  The CSV data is embedded in the `href` attribute.  You should be able to fetch that attribute and URL-decode it to fetch your data.

Comment: @TimRoberts ah okay.  My problem is that the encoded data doesn't appear until after the Chart data (CSV) is clicked on.  Is there a way to get it without figuring out how to click the Chart data (CSV) option first?

Comment: If it doesn't redraw the whole page, then either the data is embedded in the Javascript, or it makes an AJAX request to fetch it.  You may have to slog through the web page code to find that.  Have you watched the network traffic in your browser's Developer Tools to see what requests are made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JS Path Interaction:

Xpath selectors can be a bit finicky, I would revert to the basics and try to **interact with the element via the JS Path**. I was able to reproduce the error and download the report using the JS Path instead. Implement the following updated code:

```
driver.get('https://www.caiso.com/TodaysOutlook/Pages/supply.html')
driver.execute_script("el = document.querySelector('#downloadRenewablesCSV');el.click();")
```

Answer (score 2):

You were trying to click on download button without actually expanding the drop down, the element becomes interactable upon clicking the dropdown.

The `show` class is added dynamically to the `div` only once the `<button>` with text *Download* is clicked.

The below code should work after clicking on the dropdown button

```
dropdown = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='dropdownMenuRenewables']")
dropdown.click()
download_b = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@id='downloadRenewablesCSV']")
download_b.click()
```

This will download the file for you